# Google Play Service 9.2.56 drains battery within 30minutes

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-services

Google Play Service 9.2.56 drains battery within 30minutes

With the new version of google play service it drains the battery of older devices instantly. It gets incredibly hot, barely touchable.

There are tons of threads appearing on the web. Some here
Google Groups
Github

The only solution so far is to completely uninstall the service. You can not use older version since it will auto update itself soon or later. It does not care about update restrictions.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2 4.0.3

Anyone got an idea on how to solve it without uninstalling?

Comment: [Related](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/149856/131553) - I am afraid there is no other way than uninstalling and reverting to earlier versions -though that would be a short lived relief

Comment: @beeshyams Hopefully there will be a patch soon.

Answer (score 1):

My "solution" is freezing Google Play Services 9.2.56 with the disadvantage that some Apps relying on that service will not work anymore.
Restore to the previous 9.0.28 version does not solve the problem, because it will automatic be updated to 9.2.56.
I tried to find a way to contact the Android developer team at Google, no success.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to flash the whole Gapps(Google Apps) package of the same version. This happened to one of my friends.  He switched to a Custom ROM  and flashed the newest Gapps Package he could find. This is the only solution by now. Older devices have this problem because of the newer frameworks of the application. As you're using Android Ice Cream Sandwich which is a bit out-dated. Using a custom ROM will get you a newer flavour of Android such as Jelly Bean or KitKat

Google Play services have also had this issue in the past. You can use Greenify to hibernate the app (if you're rooted) but it will cause several apps to stop functioning.

As of custom ROMs, Cyanogenmod is a good option to go with. Download the latest stable version and flash it in your device. You probably don't want to flash a nightly because it's not fully stable and have features that are in beta state.  You would have to root your device for this.

[Some documentation about rooting Samsung Galaxy S2](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvyYDz1PXNAhVCrY8KHUxQAy8QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikihow.com%2FRoot-the-Samsung-Galaxy-S2&usg=AFQjCNHUGIvrtkTgxGimqCz8JMYVr0ne0Q&sig2=mrN-1N7ywG67dd6inXIFkg&bvm=bv.127178174,d.c2I)
Good Luck !!